# Not able to read map from file

Tags: java, hashmap

I tried below code to write a map into file and read it:

```
@After
public void init(Scenario scenario){
  hm.put(testNames,scenario.getStatus());

// to write code into file
        try {
            File fileOne=new File("file.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(hm);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
         ;
        } catch(Exception e) {}
  }      
//to read the file(in other java program)
        try {
            File toRead=new File("file.txt");
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(toRead);
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            HashMap<String,io.cucumber.java.Status> mapInFile=(HashMap<String,io.cucumber.java.Status>)ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
            fis.close();

  
            for(Map.Entry<String,io.cucumber.java.Status> m :mapInFile.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(m.getKey()+" : "+m.getValue());
            }
```

The code to write to file is wrapped in @After.

I am able to write into file but getting only 1 key value pair as O/P

Comment: Have you checked if there has an exception occured on writing? Because you silently swallow any exception ... Please provide your input map and output file.

Comment: "...but getting only 1 key value pair as O/P" - There is only 1 key value pair added to the map in your code snippet.  Does `hm` have entries in it before the code shown in the question gets executed?

Comment: This code with some minor fixes works ok.  In the code snippet you put one entry to the map, write it to the file, and read the map back from the file containing one entry.

Comment: I have edited the code. The code is wrapped under @After block. So after each scenario it is getting executed.